# how to verify tag of web element after it has been extracted using xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium in python with chrome driver.

Here is my scenario:

From a web page I extract all elements having `id==customer_info` or `class==prize_info` using the following code:

```
customer_or_prize_list=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="customer_info" or @class="prize_info"]')
```

Now I want to go through each element of the list 'customer_or_prize_list' and process as follows

1. if web element contains `id==customer_info` then do multi_line_text_formatting (assume it as action 1)
2. if web element contains `class==prize_info` then do single_line_text_formatting (assume it as action 2)

You can assume that a web element will not contain both id and class.

How can I process list elements using 1. and 2. above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go through each element of the list, get the attribute of the element using `get_attribute()`:

```py
for el in customer_or_prize_list:
  is_customer = "customer_info" in el.get_attribute("id")
  is_prize    = "prize_info"    in el.get_attribute("class")
```

See [this url](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute), if you want to know more about `get_attribute()`.

---

**Another way,**

why don't you divide the list into two small lists, like below:

```py
customer_list=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="customer_info"]')
for e in customer_list:
  '''do multi_line_text_formatting'''

prize_list=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="prize_info"]')
for e in prize_list:
  '''do single_line_text_formatting'''
```

Comment: yeah , i am currently using the two list approach . I will try get_attribute and let you know . Meanwhile can you suggest me a way to combine xpaths . My specific case is - I want web element that has attribute id='next button' but its class attribute should not contain the word 'disabled' . Thanks .

Comment: I verified 'get_attribute' approach . It works well . Thanks . In my previous comment - I had asked that can you provide me a single query to filter web elements such that its id should be 'next_button' and its class attribute should not contain 'disabled' ?

Comment: I have tried this xpath -- '//*[@id="next_button" and not(contains(@class,"disabled"))]'  -- but it is not valid .

Comment: @user1371666  In my opinion, the xpath `'//*[@id="next_button" and not(contains(@class,"disabled"))]'` is correct and meets your requirements. Moreover, I have written a HTML demo and verified the xpath worked.